# Magento Import Product With image in CSV

Tags: magento

i am upload a csv file that contain products and its image .
when i read the documentation they says that you need to place images in intall_directory/media/import/file_name.jpg

I do the same thing also give right to folder but when i import it says 
Image does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you provide image path starting with '/'.
For example if one image reside in install_directory/media/import/file1.jpg then in CSV, image path should be as follow

/file1.jpg

In short, image path is relative to media/import directory

And also check that folder has necessary permission.